# Grails - Spring Security REST - 302 Response net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: ajax, rest, grails, spring-security, restful-authentication

I am using the [grails-spring-security-rest](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest) plugin to secure my rest api.

I am unable to call the rest api successfully via AJAX using the plugin. I am receiving a 302 response which is causing a redirect loop.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8084/app/api/controller",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <TOKEN>');},
});
```

I have tested non-authenticated, with the plugin removed and everything is working fine.

I am able to successfully call the rest api with curl:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer <TOKEN>" http://localhost:8084/app/api/controller
```

I have a the following configuration in place:

BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC5", {
    excludes: 'spring-security-core'
}
```

Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'com.app.security.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

I have ensured that the proper authentication token is being sent in the headers, here is a snippet from the request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8084/app/api/controller/
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization:Bearer <TOKEN>
```

Looking for whether I am doing something wrong in my submission, or if possibly this is a bug in the plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same bug, did you get anywhere, cweston ?

Comment: @OliverTynes I did not have time to continue investigating the issue, so I decided to not use the plugin for now.  I did create a ticket [here](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/94#issuecomment-50632599) though, if you would like to follow up.

Comment: @OliverTynes Please let me know if you are able to resolve the issue.

Comment: See my answer..


In other news, I just made my own auth plugin for rest from scratch that just uses the original @Secured annotations. I will try to publish in early november, it's meant to be a REST drop-in replacement for spring security. You'll basically just have to search&replace for the spring security annotation import to replace with my annotation + change springSecurityService.ifAnyGranted() to use restSecurityService.ifAnyGranted() etc..

You can inject your own userdetail validator and password encoder if you're not using bcrypt (standard in my plugin).

Comment: @OliverTynes What is the name of your plugin? Can you post the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the remember me filter.

Use like this:

`'/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'`

This.. 'bug' will only happen if you've used the app with regular spring security before, because then you'll have a cookie that will hijack the whole filter process and try to log you in (and redirect you), making a redirection war between the custom rest plugin filter and the original spring security.